# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured s3 Static website + CloudFront with lambda@Edge + aws cognito.
When I open Cloudfront URL after authenticating with cognito it shows above errors that it is not able to load the page due to security issues.

Repo: https://github.com/qoomon/aws-s3-bucket-browser

Link to refer: https://medium.com/@saurishkar/setting-up-aws-http-authentication-on-cloudfront-s3-using-cognito-and-lambda-edge-166ee38d471e

added below line to HTML but still gives an error.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' * ">
```

Error: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbT1I.png)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSPs can be expressed in HTTP headers and in HTML `<meta>` tags, but HTTP headers trump `<meta>` tags.

If you **added** a CSP using a `<meta>` tag but you have CSP related error messages before, then you haven't done anything useful since the existing HTTP headers will override the `<meta>` tag.

Remove the `<meta>` tag again. Then change the HTTP headers.